# how to use bpk vpn windowns files in ubntu

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have one vpn setting file which have been introduced by my university site to use for connecting to university internet by vpn setting which is like this file when opened in text app:

```
[VPN Connection]
Encoding=1
PBVersion=4
Type=2
AutoLogon=0
UseRasCredentials=1
LowDateTime=-1512233328
HighDateTime=30693892
DialParamsUID=99902812
Guid=333052EA7C10B4448D790BB85AE4DEA8
VpnStrategy=2
ExcludedProtocols=0
LcpExtensions=1
DataEncryption=8
SwCompression=0
NegotiateMultilinkAlways=0
SkipDoubleDialDialog=0
DialMode=0
OverridePref=15
RedialAttempts=3
RedialSeconds=60
IdleDisconnectSeconds=0
RedialOnLinkFailure=1
CallbackMode=0
CustomDialDll=
CustomDialFunc=
CustomRasDialDll=
ForceSecureCompartment=0
DisableIKENameEkuCheck=0
AuthenticateServer=0
ShareMsFilePrint=1
BindMsNetClient=1
SharedPhoneNumbers=0
GlobalDeviceSettings=0
PrerequisiteEntry=
PrerequisitePbk=
PreferredPort=VPN4-0
PreferredDevice=WAN Miniport (PPTP)
PreferredBps=0
PreferredHwFlow=1
PreferredProtocol=1
PreferredCompression=1
PreferredSpeaker=1
PreferredMdmProtocol=0
PreviewUserPw=1
PreviewDomain=1
PreviewPhoneNumber=0
ShowDialingProgress=1
ShowMonitorIconInTaskBar=1
CustomAuthKey=0
AuthRestrictions=512
IpPrioritizeRemote=1
IpInterfaceMetric=0
IpHeaderCompression=0
IpAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDnsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDns2Address=0.0.0.0
IpWinsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpWins2Address=0.0.0.0
IpAssign=1
IpNameAssign=1
IpDnsFlags=0
IpNBTFlags=1
TcpWindowSize=0
UseFlags=2
IpSecFlags=0
IpDnsSuffix=
Ipv6Assign=1
Ipv6Address=::
Ipv6PrefixLength=0
Ipv6PrioritizeRemote=1
Ipv6InterfaceMetric=0
Ipv6NameAssign=1
Ipv6DnsAddress=::
Ipv6Dns2Address=::
Ipv6Prefix=0000000000000000
Ipv6InterfaceId=0000000000000000
DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute=0
DisableMobility=0
NetworkOutageTime=0
IDI=
IDR=
ImsConfig=0
IdiType=0
IdrType=0
ProvisionType=0
PreSharedKey=
CacheCredentials=1
NumCustomPolicy=0
NumEku=0
UseMachineRootCert=0
NumServers=0
RouteVersion=1
NumRoutes=0
NumNrptRules=0
AutoTiggerCapable=0
NumAppIds=0
NumClassicAppIds=0
SecurityDescriptor=
ApnInfoProviderId=
ApnInfoUsername=
ApnInfoPassword=
ApnInfoAccessPoint=
ApnInfoAuthentication=1
ApnInfoCompression=0
DeviceComplianceEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEku=
DeviceComplianceSsoIssuer=
FlagsSet=0
Options=0
DisableDefaultDnsSuffixes=0
NumTrustedNetworks=0
NumDnsSearchSuffixes=0
PowershellCreatedProfile=0
ProxyFlags=0
ProxySettingsModified=0
ProvisioningAuthority=
AuthTypeOTP=0
GREKeyDefined=0
NumPerAppTrafficFilters=0
AlwaysOnCapable=0
DeviceTunnel=0
PrivateNetwork=0

NETCOMPONENTS=
ms_msclient=1
ms_server=1

MEDIA=rastapi
Port=VPN4-0
Device=WAN Miniport (PPTP)

DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber=vpn.stmu.ac.ir
AreaCode=
CountryCode=0
CountryID=0
UseDialingRules=0
Comment=
FriendlyName=
LastSelectedPhone=0
PromoteAlternates=0
TryNextAlternateOnFail=1
```

the main file is accessible [here](http://s7.picofile.com/file/8389045126/vpn.pbk.html), with name of **vpn.pbk**.

SO when i want to add this file in VPN import file like this:

[image]
 i get this error:

[image]
so i asked here is there any other way to insert that file information i side of it manually to Ubuntu VPN setting like this:

[image]

Comment: this seems to be a definition file for microsoft windows L2TP. On ubuntu you would need to use the information inside to add a vpn connection yourself. But before you can do so, you need to make sure `network-manager-l2tp-gnome` is installed and probably reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I must try more on it but now our University is closed because of Corona virus which is expanding rapidly in my country and town, and the government is ...